# Index of array for an element with in array in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala

I have an Array of Array:

```
val arr = Array(Array("1","page"),Array("1","thankyou"))
```

I know that `indexOf` function is used to get the first index of an element in an array but not sure how to get the index of outer array based on inner array elements.
Like index of "page" in arr is 0 and index of "thankyou" is 1.
Kindly suggest a solution in Scala.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
arr.map(_.indexOf("page"))     // 1, -1
arr.map(_.indexOf("thankyou")) // -1, 1
```

for the indexes in inner arrays (`-1` means "not found") and

```
arr.indexWhere(_.exists(_ == "page"))     // 0
arr.indexWhere(_.exists(_ == "thankyou")) // 1
```

for the index in an outer array.